# Custom Deep Link is not opening App when is closed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-deep-link

I have a custom scheme for deep link in my app but when it's closed nothing happen.

```
public class DeepLinkReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String deepLinkUri = intent.getStringExtra(DeepLinkHandler.EXTRA_URI);

    if (intent.getBooleanExtra(DeepLinkHandler.EXTRA_SUCCESSFUL, false)) {
        Timber.d("onReceive: Success deep linking: %s", deepLinkUri);
    } else {
        String errorMessage = intent.getStringExtra(DeepLinkHandler.EXTRA_ERROR_MESSAGE);
        Timber.e("onReceive: Error deep linking %s with message: %s ", deepLinkUri, errorMessage);
    }
}
}
```

This validation is always false

Here is my `intent-filter`

```
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:scheme="myapp" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Why are you using Broadcast Receiver for deep link handling ?

Comment: @KamalNayan because I'm using DeepLinkDispatch from Airbnb lib

Comment: According to the documentation >. `You can optionally register a BroadcastReceiver to be called on any incoming deep link into your app. DeepLinkDispatch will use LocalBroadcastManager to broadcast an Intent with any success or failure when deep linking. The intent will be populated with these extras:`   So this is just a local broadcast of the deep link success of failure, and can not be used for receiving deeplinks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `intent-filter` inside activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="example.com"
                android:scheme="https" />
            <data
                android:host="example.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>

 </activity>
```

Now this activity will be launched whenever the link with the host name will be clicked.

Comment: I already added this intent-filter for normal links. In my case I have some custom links that will open my app. Eg: myapp://customlink

Comment: @WellingtonYogui also for them you need to add intent filters with `android:host="myapp://customlink"`